# Hudson proxy configuration on amazon EC2-VPC instance

Tags: proxy, amazon-vpc, hudson

I am using EC2 VPC instance.

For Hudson installation of plugins, I hit the command `java -jar Hudson.war --httpPort=8888`

After this, I opened url `http://127.0.0.1:8888` in instance's internet explorer. Hudson asks for proxy configuration to access the Internet. FYI, I am able to open other websites.

**Snapshot:**

[image: pic]

Is it because I am using VPC instance? If yes, please help. TIA.

Comment: Does your instance have a Public or Elastic IP associated with it? If not you will need to have NAT or an HTTP proxy for it to reach the Internet. Can you reach external sites with IE\curl from the instance?

Comment: @TheFiddlerWins: I do have Elastic IP associated with my instance and I can reach external sites with IE fron the instance